# Error while deploying ASP.net website

Tags: asp.net, web-config

```
Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Office, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


Line 43:                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
Line 44:                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
Line 45:                <add assembly="Office, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"/>
Line 46:                <add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"/></assemblies>
Line 47:        </compilation>


Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\toolbar\web.config    Line: 45 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Office, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Can Anyone help me to solve this problem??I am using windows server 2008 to deploy my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed the Microsoft Office Primary Interop Assemblies?  If not, they are available here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa159923(office.11).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Set to Office assembly at your references CopyLocal property to true or put it to hosting manually.

Comment: How can i do it? can you please guide me?

Comment: Open your project at VS, open References folder, find Office assembly there. Open properties window(F4). Find CopyLocal property for assembly, set it to true, then publish your project

Comment: i am using Vwebdeveloper 2008 and the project works fine on my local machine the error comes when i move it onto remote server

Comment: i am using Vwebdeveloper 2008 and the project works fine on my local machine the error comes when i move it onto remote server,i have not installed VS and office on server.what do i need to do??